# alternatives to pyspark to query a csv file locally (no distributed computation needed)

Tags: python, pyspark, csv, library

I am reading a csv file with pyspark to extract some information from it. I am running pyspark locally and I do not need distributed computation. On the contrary I need some plotting library such as matplotlib to plot data. I know there are some workarounds to do it with pyspark but I found it very complicated.

My question is: is there any alternative to pyspark, possibly python-native, that allows to query a csv file allowing to use python libraries?

Comment: you can use batch-mode (called chunks) from pandas read_csv - find examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas and official source https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2):

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can do it. It can read in a csv file with a single line and put the data in a dataframe that you can manipulate.